# FIrefox - Why does ALT+A select all text and not CTRL+A?

Tags: keyboard, firefox, shortcut-keys

Since I am so used to using the standard `Ctrl+-a` to select all, I am wondering why in Firefox I have to use `Alt-a`?

I just downloaded this [Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) -- in the hope of solving this issue, but on opening the preferences for this add-on I see that the keyboard command is already set-up as `Ctrl-a`. However that is not the case in reality.

Is this something deeper in Ubuntu that needs changing? I think there are some other programs, although I cant think of them of the top of my head that also use the `Alt-a` to select all, although there are some that don't. Leaf Pad for example uses the standard `Ctrl-a`.

I just upgraded to 14.04, and was using 13.10 before that, in either case the problem is the exactly the same.

Comment: that's weird. Ctrl+a works fine in firefox for me. Maybe you have a bad keyboard map ?

Comment: I can use CTRL + A to select all text in Firefox as well as ALT + A. Could you try starting Firefox without add-ons? `Menu` > `?` > `Restart with Add-ons Disabled...`, I assume CTRL + A is working in Leaf Pad so this is a Firefox issue.

Comment: I restarted with all plugins and add-ons diabled, but still the same issue. `ctrl-a` puts the cursor to the beginning of any line of text that the cursor may be on, just for added info. This `alt-a` for select all has been this way since I first started using Ubuntu several months ago.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/208310/ctrl-a-doesnt-work-in-browsers possible duplicate ?

Comment: Yep, the gnome tweak tool solved the issue, as outlined in 1 of the answers on the link you just pasted. However the Tweak Tool, is a bit different now in 14.10. You need `Keyboard and mouse` menu and change `Key theme` to `default`.